# Haskell: turning a non-infinite list into an infinite one + laziness (euler 391)

Tags: haskell

I've written the following Haskell code to produce a list where the nth element is the number of 1s in writing 1..n as binary numbers (it's related to euler 391, incidentally):

```
buildList :: a -> (a -> a) -> [a]
buildList start f = start : buildList (f start) f

differences :: [[Int]]
differences = buildList [0] (\x -> x ++ map (+1) x)

sequenceK' :: Int -> [Int]
sequenceK' n = tail $ scanl (+) 0 (last $ take n differences)
```

which results in `sequenceK' n` giving a list of 2^(n-1) elements.

This question has two parts:

a) Why does the time taken to compute `head $ sequenceK' n` increase with n? -- due to ghc's laziness, I would expect the time to remain more or less constant.

b) Is it possible to define an infinite version of this list so that I can do things like `take` and `takeWhile` without having to worry about the value of the parameter passed to `sequenceK'`?

Comment: Your `buildList` is just [`flip iterate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:iterate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) Because you're calling `last $ take n differences`, which has to do more work the bigger `n` is.

b) Yep, it's possible. The least-thinking solution is to just take the earliest element we see at each particular depth:

```
*Main> take 20 . map head . transpose $ differences
[0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,1,2,2,3]
```

The better solution is to generate only the meaningful bits. We can do this by observing the following equality:

```
differences' = 1 : (differences' >>= \x -> [x, x+1])
```

Actually, this is slightly off, as you can probably guess:

```
*Main> take 20 differences'
[1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,1,2,2,3,2,3]
```

But it's easily fixed by just tacking a `0` on front.

Comment: Rewriting `differences'` as `differences' = 1 : concatMap (\x -> [x,x+1]) differences'` might help make the equivalence slightly clearer.  (I kept trying to get it to work with `map`, myself.  This highlights the difference.)